# Specific category layout update, custom product collection - missing toolbar?

Tags: magento, layout, toolbar, categories

In local.xml, I created a layout update so I can display a custom filtered product collection.

This is in local.xml:

```
<CATEGORY_7>
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/cashcrop.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>

            </block>
        </block>
</CATEGORY_7>
```

The template file is a copy of list.phtml, but modified to filter the collection:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    //$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('randament', array('in' => array(101, 102)))
    ->load()
    ;
    $this->setCollection($_productCollection);
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

This works, I get 105 products in the collection. **The problem is the toolbar - it is not being shown**. Has anyone any idea why the toolbar is not shown? (I know this `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>` return an empty string, but I don't understand why.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-initialize everything. Try this and see if it works:

```
<CATEGORY_7>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <tpl>catalog/product/cashcrop.phtml</tpl>
        </action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_7>
```

Also, I would be wary of using auto-increment data in scripts or layout files. I'd be inclined to put this in the layout update for the category in the DB. May not be a concern for your environment, but the 7 is an arbitrary feature from the storage backend as opposed to something that is more meaningful, such as the category name.

Comment: I agree with you, and I tried this as well, still no toolbar, no pagination, just the entire collection thrown on the page. And I agree with you about placing this in local.xml, this was just a last effort to see it worked. Initially I had the update place in the category's Custom Layout Update section. Personally I reckon the toolbar is lost as a result of the update or, the toolbar is not being invoked since I am circumventing the expected call     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); but that just speculation...

Comment: Best DDx would be to do the above but pass in the original template (*catalog/product/list.phtml*) as your param and see if it works. If so then the issue is with your template - highly likely given that you are not using the original product collection which the pager etc are expecting. Product list view is not a clean area as various objects in view and model layer are bound through the registry. You need to do your work higher up in the pre-rendering phase i.e. not in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out myself. Overriding the template is fine, and it's enough if placed in the category's Custom Layout Update section; no need to place it in local.xml.

The trouble is with the _beforeHtml() function in Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php, where the toolbar is being initialized by the blocks' _getProductCollection() function which always returns an empty collection, because it tries to obtain the current category's product collection.

So as a quick and dirty fix, I simply copied the code from _beforeHtml() function, and inserted it directly in my cashcrop.phtml template. The top of the template looks like this now:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('randament', array('in' => array(101, 102)))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('inflorire', array('in' => array(97)))
                        ->addMinimalPrice()
                        ->addFinalPrice()
                        ->addTaxPercents();

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);

    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
    $collection = $_productCollection;

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
        $toolbar->setModes($modes);
    }

    // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
    $toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);

    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
        'collection' => $_productCollection
    ));

    $_productCollection->load();
?>
```

I am aware this may not be the ideal solution, but it's working. If anyone else has a better solution, I would love to hear about it.

Cheers,
Michael.